# code browsing, refactoring, auto completion in Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

I recently switched to Emacs and still finding my way through it.
I code in C++ and was wondering what tools out there extend Emacs to support code browsing (finding a symbol etc), refactoring and code completion.
I have heard of:

- cedet
- etags
- cscope

But I'm so confused about what I need. Some places say that cedet provides all of the functionality but other places say that I need to invoke etags for cedet to work properly.

Can someone clear this up for me? Do I need all of these tools?

Answer (score 17):

Maybe you will find my [article](http://xtalk.msk.su/~ott/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) about Cedet useful. Cedet has support for etags, gtags, cscope and other tools.

But refactoring is missing. You may need to look into the [Xrefactory](http://www.xref.sk/xrefactory/main.html) tool (but it isn't free)

Comment: I have re-config the cedet for my emacs acorrding to you guide and config files. Oh, greate. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

**Cscope** is very good as "find symbol" usage tool. It is very fast.
**Etags** will show you your class hierarchy and will help you to find method definition/declaration.

So these two tools are must have and they are independent.

**Cedet.** It is kind of replacement of these two tools above with additional features. So your choice either cscope/etags or cedet.

Answer (score 3):

For refactoring, I started using emacs exclusively for this and related tasks after I read [this article](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/find_replace_inter.html) by emacs hacker Xah Lee.

For autocompletion, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750267/emacs-tab-completion-of-local-python-variables). Personally, I've found [yasnippet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yasnippet) very helpful throughout the years.

Answer (score 2):

gtags (http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) is also available and perhaps simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like cedet. It makes Emacs take an hour to load. The auto-complete feature has never worked quite right with me. I don't need its project-management nor its UML features. 
The only thing I miss about it is the Emacs Code Browser, which is very useful but requires cedet

I would advice you to just use cscope and etags and see how you like them. You can install cedet later once you're more familiar with emacs.

Comment: You can use only needed parts of Cedet. Name completion works fine in latest versions of Cedet (but may be you'll need to perform some customization)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog article](http://www.wolinlabs.com/blog/emacs.global.speedbar.html) about using Global/gtags and Speedbar for code browsing you might find useful...  (I also thought CEDET was a bit slow... and extremely complicated to set up =)