# Emacs code completion for C/C++?

Tags: emacs, code-completion

1. [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete)
2. [Xrefactory](http://www.xref-tech.com/xrefactory/main.html)
3. [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml)
4. ?

What can you recommend me ?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671412/code-browsing-refactoring-auto-completion-in-emacs

Comment: autocomplete package could also take information from Cedet/Semantic.  For which language do you want to use auto completion?
Xrefactory, as i remember is non-free

Comment: Thanks Alex, your tutorial was very helpful :)

Comment: I almost freaked out 'cause at first I read it "Emacs code COMPILATION for C/C++".. I was like "It compiles C/C++ code, too?!?!" Thank God I had read it wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CEDET is just great, certainly needs some time at the beginning but worth it though.

Answer (score 9):

You can try [company-mode](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/company-mode/). It's a multi-backend in-buffer completion mechanism.
Watch the [screencast](http://www.screentoaster.com/watch/stU0lSRERIR1pYRFVdXVlRVFFV/company_mode_for_gnu_emacs) to get an idea of how it works.

Some of the back-ends are:

- CEDET Semantic
- dabbrev
- XCode
- [PySmell](http://code.google.com/p/pysmell/)
- [Ropemacs](http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropemacs.html)
- [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/)

And it's also available via [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/).

Comment: Any tutorials on how to install CEDET or GNU Global, and get them working with company-mode? Those don't seem to be available in ELPA

Answer (score 8):

You could also use an autocomplete plugin for clang as long as your source compiles with it.
links:

- https://github.com/Golevka/emacs-clang-complete-async
- https://github.com/brianjcj/auto-complete-clang
- https://github.com/mikeandmore/auto-complete-clang or
- the mode which is included in the  clang-source: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/utils/clang-completion-mode.el

Answer (score 7):

#### [GCCSense](https://web.archive.org/web/20151215163745/http://cx4a.org:80/software/gccsense/)

From the author of [Auto Complete Mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229095812/http://cx4a.org:80/software/auto-complete/). It uses gcc to find candidates for code completion as the name suggests.

[image: emacs gccsense screenshot]

Comment: #archeology I tried several times (2 or 3) to use GCCsense during the last 10 years without success. Did you actually manage to set it up and make it works properly. Is the completion OK now? The fact that private data appear in the sample completion is not good sign...

Comment: @Ugo: I don't know current status. It worked at the time I've tried it.

Comment: never managed to make it build!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use etags.

For emacs integration:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/etags.html

For how to run etags.
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/etags.1.html

As a bonus, this blog post describes a bit more emacs setup and how to use etags.
http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/emacs.html

Edit:
To answer the comment, after runnning etags across your code, you can complete words with C-x t(that's what it's bound to on my machine.)  Or you can call the *tag-search* method.

Comment: Yeah that's what I actually use, but as far as I can see, doesn't provide code completion feature. Does it ?

Comment: for C/C++ gnu global is better

Comment: CEDET is far more powerful than GNU Global

Answer (score 0):

to be honest for i like plain old dabbrev-expand (M-/), yes it doesn't use any contextual information other than what characters are adjacent in the open buffers, but on the plus side it doesn't use any contextual information ;) this means you can complete from text you have written first in tests or comments.

for other options http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryCompletion

Answer (score -3):

When I'm editing python code in Emacs, I like and use pysmell for code completion:

http://code.google.com/p/pysmell/

Comment: Way to answer a question that wasn't asked.

Comment: TS asked about c/c++ code completetion for Emacs not python...