# Is it possible to make C++ autohinting in emacs cc-mode?

Tags: emacs, cc-mode

I'm no sure if "autohinting" is correct word but I can explain

for example when I write

```
std::
```

I want to see the list of available things there, and same for "." and "->" , I hope that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind `.` and `>` with `semantic-complete-self-insert` command, that will try to show list of possible completions. Although I don't know, is it possible out of box to bind it to `::` sequence (although, it should be possible with some amount of emacs lisp code)

Comment: I'm just now looking into your config and cedet tutorial :) and... thinking about merge with your configuration (at least cedet configuration).

Answer (score 1):

[code browsing, refactoring, auto completion in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671412/code-browsing-refactoring-auto-completion-in-emacs)

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it looks related. I think Etags might be what you are looking for.