# ctags c++ finds the first instance of function regardless of class

Tags: c++, c, linux, vim, emacs

I use ctags (-e) and it works very well. However, when I search for a member function ctags returns the first definition it finds. For example:

```
ClassA classA;
classA.Initialize();
classA.DoSomething();

ClassB classB;
classB.Initialize();
classB.PerformAction();
```

If I search for the tag `Initialize()` (`M-.` or `g^]`) on `classA.Initialize()` I expect to go to `ClassA::Initialize()`. If it so happens that there is another class with the same method and its tag appears before `classA`'s tag in the tag file then (let's say that's `ClassB::Initialize()`) I get taken for a ride to `ClassB::Initialize()`.

However, if when I type `M-.` and I ammend the tag I want to visit to `ClassA::Initialize()` then I go to `ClassA::Initialize()`. Is there a way to make this automatic?

This behaviour is consistent across emacs and vim.

Furthermore, with GNU global (gtags) will not even find `ClassA::Initialize()`. It will just print out all classes that have an `Initialize()` method.

EDIT:

If the question is yet not clear I'm asking whether there is a plugin which will examine the method (e.g. is it a member function which is accessed via `.` or `->`) and if it is will find the type of object and then look for `Object::Method` instead of for method.

This is a simple functionality. For example:

1. Check if tag is a method.
2. If it is a method is it a member of a class.
3. If a member of a class parse code before current cursor and find declaration (ClassA classA).
4. Look for `ClassA::Initialize()` if all of the above is true instead of `Initialize()`.

Is that any clearer?

Comment: Yes, neither ctags nor gtags have any way to disambiguate between ClassA::Initialize() and ClassB::Initialize(), which means that you'll have to give them more information (for example by choosing in the list that gtags outputs). Could you please state more clearly what your question is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [code browsing, refactoring, auto completion in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671412/code-browsing-refactoring-auto-completion-in-emacs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctags only indexes your code. You only use it to generate a `tags` file while the searching is done by your editor. How it does the searching is your editor's business and ctags has nothing to do with it.

When you do `<C-]>` over a method name, Vim jumps to the first match it finds. Because it has no means to analyse your code and your thoughts, it can't decide what match you actually want.

The closest thing it has is the notion of "priority", see `:h tag-priority`, but it won't really help you.

And the usual way to deal with that limitation is to use a command that lists all the matches, like `g]` or `g<C-]>`.

Comment: Or use `:tn` until you find the one you want.

Comment: Indeed, at the expense of clobbering the tagstack.